# Extract from tar.gz by file name

Tags: gzip, tar

I've got a large amount of files inside .tar.gz.

Is it (programmatically) possible to extract a file by its filename, without the overhead of decompressing other files?

Comment: Hope this will helps you :- https://askubuntu.com/questions/168795/how-do-i-extract-a-specific-file-from-a-tar-archive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll split the reply into two parts

> Is it (programmatically) possible to extract a file by its filename

yes, it is possible to extract a file by its filename.

```
tar xzf tarfile.tar filename
```

> without the overhead of decompressing other files?

In order to extract a file from a compressed tar file the `tar` program has to find the file you want. If that is the first file in the tarfile, then it only has to uncompress that. If the file isn't the first in the tarfile the `tar` program needs to scan through the tarfile until it finds the file you want. To do that is MUST uncompress the preceding files in the tarfile. That doesn't mean it has to extract them to disk or buffer these files in memory. It will stream the uncompression so that them memory overhead isn't significant.